# PyQt5 Video Player on Mac zooming in

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a video player in PyQt5, when I run this on a Windows machine it formats the video into the frame properly but when I run the same program on my Mac it makes the frame zoom in to try and fit the res of the video? I think. Is there a way to fix this issue?

How it looks before a video is loaded

[image]

How it looks after a video is loaded on Mac

[image]

Code for the window:

```
class VideoWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideoWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt Video Player")
        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)

        videoWidget = QVideoWidget()

        self.playButton = QPushButton()
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.playButton.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))

        self.errorLabel = QLabel()
        self.errorLabel.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred,
                                      QSizePolicy.Maximum)

        # Create new action
        openAction = QAction(QIcon('stream.png'), '&Stream', self)
        openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openAction.setStatusTip('Start a Stream')
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.openFile)

        # Create new action
        connectAction = QAction(QIcon('connect.png'), '&Connect', self)
        connectAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+C')
        connectAction.setStatusTip('Connect to a Stream')
        connectAction.triggered.connect(self.openConnectionList)

        # Create exit action
        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.exitCall)

        # Create menu bar and add action
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        menuBar.setNativeMenuBar(False)
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(connectAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        # Create a widget for window contents
        wid = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(wid)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(videoWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.errorLabel)

        # Set widget to contain window contents
        wid.setLayout(layout)

        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.error.connect(self.handleError)

    def openFile(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Stream",
                                                  QDir.homePath())

        if fileName != '':
            self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(
                QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName)))
            self.mediaPlayer.play()

    def openConnectionList(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = connectionList()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    def exitCall(self):
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def handleError(self):
        self.errorLabel.setText("Error: " + self.mediaPlayer.errorString())


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        videoPlayer = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        player = VideoWindow()
        player.resize(640, 480)
        player.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

EDIT::::
Youtube video to show error happening [Error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZgtEJsoZQM&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by enabling High-DPI scaling when you create your application:

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_EnableHighDpiScaling'):
        PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)

    if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps'):
        PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)

    videoPlayer = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    player = VideoWindow()
    player.resize(640, 480)
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, have been working on a DB project all day. I added that and the exact same thing is happening.

Comment: Hi, sorry about. I have tried your code and could not reproduce the problem. Are you using the latest version of PyQt?

Comment: According to my machine I am using PyQt5   version 5.11.3, I can only get this error to replicate on my Mac, it scales fine on both windows and linux machines. It only happens after a video has loaded in also.

Comment: I added a link to a youtube video of the error happening to the OP.

Comment: Sorry mate, I tried your code on my mac and it's working fine (the display is full-hd), are you sure the high-dpi settings in my questions do not fix the issue?

Comment: The video I posted on the OP is after adding those settings you posted. It must be my machine that's acting up! thank you for your help, if you don't mind could you add what you used as imports in your answer?